# change image source programmatically

Tags: c++, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I cannot figure out how to dynamically load an image from the disk to a Xaml image control.

```
<Image x:Name="imgLogo" ....../>
```

Then in my c++ class, i cannot get any examples working that I have found. Most are in c#. One annoyance is that I keep seeing System.Windows.Media::ImageSource used, but that is not in my framework.

Can someone please show me an example. I'm coming from the iOS world and am not used to MS and their frameworks.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it's in C# but should be fairly easy to convert:

```
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging;

<Image Margin="5" Source="{Binding BMImage}" Height="100"/>


bmImage = new BitmapImage();
bmImage.UriSource = new Uri(new Uri(
     *your file path*, 
     *your image name*);


BitmapImage bmImage;
public BitmapImage BMImage
{
    get
    {
        return bmImage;
    }
}
```

Taken from [here](http://windows8applicationdevelopment.blogspot.com/2012/09/loading-resources.html) (my blog).

To change the image, just change the value of `bmImage` and call `NotifyPropertyChanged(()=>BMImage);` (assuming you have that setup)

See [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/0f5d56ae-5e57-48e1-9cd9-993115b027b9/sourcecode?fileId=44756&pathId=2647585) for Microsoft's example of how to use images.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging) for the `Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging` namespace.

Comment: Thank you for the example. The first problem that I'm running into is that I cannot fine BitmapImage in the framework. The documentation says it's under System.Windows.Media.Imaging, but there is no such location on my box. I type in "Windows::Media::Imaging::BitmapImage" and it cannot find the Imaging namespace. Any idea why?

Comment: I do understand about binding. I am just having an issue with the namespace.

Comment: Have you tried `using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging;` or whatever it is for C++

Comment: `Windows::UI::Xaml::Media::Imaging` I think Windows::Media::Imaging is for desktop applications.

Comment: MyDogIsBox was correct. The I was looking at the wrong framework. BitmpapImage is located under the Xaml branch. Thanks!

Comment: @HCHogan If this answers your question then you should mark it as the answer, although I do appreciate the upvote as well. :-)