# How do I bind image in WinRT to a listbox

Tags: vb.net, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime

I am new to the xaml programming. I Have been trying to bind multiple images to a listbox with no luck. I am able to see the text but not the image in winrt app. Below is the code:

```
Imports Windows.Storage.Pickers
Imports Windows.Storage

Public NotInheritable Class MainPage
    Inherits Page

    Dim p As System.Uri

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Invoked when this page is about to be displayed in a Frame.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="e">Event data that describes how this page was reached.  The Parameter
    ''' property is typically used to configure the page.</param>
    Protected Overrides Sub OnNavigatedTo(e As Navigation.NavigationEventArgs)

    End Sub

Private Async Sub SelectFileName_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles _SelectFileName.Click

        Dim SelectedFileNameObject As New FileOpenPicker
        SelectedFileNameObject.FileTypeFilter.Add("*")

Dim SelectedFileName As IReadOnlyList(Of StorageFile) = Await SelectedFileNameObject.PickMultipleFilesAsync

        Dim a As New ObservableCollection(Of ImageLoc)
        For i As Integer = 0 To SelectedFileName.Count - 1

            p = New Uri(SelectedFileName.Item(i).Path.ToString, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)

            a.Add(New ImageLoc() With {.ImageLocation = _SelectedFileName.Item(i).Path.ToString, .LineFour = p})

        Next
        ListName.ItemsSource = a

    End Sub

End class

Public Class ImageLoc
    Public location As String

    Property ImageLocation() As String
        Get
            Return location
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            location = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public b As Uri
    Public Property LineFour() As Uri
        Get
            Return b

        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Uri)
            b = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

The Xaml is:

```
<Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <StackPanel Height="auto" Width="auto" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button x:Name="SelectFileName" Width="100" Height="50" Content="Browse Files" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,10,40,0"/>
        <ListBox x:Name="ListName" Width="700" Height="auto">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                      <TextBlock Text="{Binding ImageLocation}" Height="auto" Width="auto"/>
                        <Image Height="100" Width="100">
                            <Image.Source>
                                <BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding Path=LineFour}"/>
                            </Image.Source>
                        </Image>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: change <BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding Path=LineFour}"/> to <BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding LineFour}"/> ?

Answer (score 0):

For one, you don't actually have to do the longhand `BitmapImage` code. The `Image` control spy ports binding an `ImageSource` or a `URI` directly to its `Source` property. Also, are you sure that the Uris that you're passing are in the correct format? Sometimes they need to have the package name prefix on the front for them to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

See [change image source programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12323864/change-image-source-programmatically/12323937#12323937)

Basically:

```
<Image Margin="5" Source="{Binding BMImage}" Height="100"/>

BitmapImage bmImage;
public BitmapImage BMImage
{
    get
    {
        return bmImage;
    }
}

bmImage = new BitmapImage();
bmImage.UriSource = new Uri(new Uri(
     *your file path*, 
     *your image name*);
```

For more examples see my blog [here](http://windows8applicationdevelopment.blogspot.com/2012/09/loading-resources.html).

Comment: Sorry this is in C#.  I'm not conversant in VB.